# What is "Object Space Lighting"?

Tags: rendering, real-time, lighting, space

Looking at [Star Swarm](http://www.oxidegames.com/star-swarm/), a demo for the Nitrous engine, I found this little line:
"Nitrous uses Object Space Lighting, the same techniques used in film, including real-time film-quality motion blur."

I tried looking around for anything on "object space lighting" or "object space rendering" but couldn't come up with anything. When I hear "object space" I think of doing it per-object but I was hoping to find a more detailed description of the method.

Does anyone know anything about "object space lighting" and if so could you go into some technical details(how its done, pros, cons, etc)?

Comment: Have you seen this? Not a whole lot of info but some.  http://www.gamedev.net/topic/573051-lighting-in-object-space/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Star Swarm developers this helps them with LOD and enables greater shading scaling. Based on this I guess its simply texture space lighting.

> Because we do what we’re calling object space lighting, we calculate the projected size of each of those objects on screen, and based on that we shade it in a priority manner based on how large they are. We can scale the shading quality at a different frequency than we scale the geometry level or something else.

[A deep dive into the making of the eye-popping Star Swarm demo (interview)](http://venturebeat.com/2014/01/21/a-deep-dive-into-the-making-of-the-eye-popping-star-swarm-demo-interview/view-all/)